# Errors when installing the package "Rhtslib"

Tags: r

I tried to install the Rhtslib package but got several errors, including:

- `unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]`
- `too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]`
- `unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]`

I feel like there may be some larger underlying issue that is later causing all of these errors. Can someone help me identify where I'm going wrong? Here is the output when I tried to install it:

```
install.packages("~/R/win-library/4.0/Rhtslib_1.22.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/dell/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

installing source package 'Rhtslib' ...
** using non-staged installation via StagedInstall field
** libs
*** arch - i386
cd "htslib-1.7" && /usr/bin/make -f "C:/PROGRA1/R/R-401.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "Makefile.Rhtslib.win"
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsTRXyv/R.INSTALL24fc3c222fea/Rhtslib/src-i386/htslib-1.7'
Makefile.Rhtslib.win:131: warning: overriding recipe for target '.c.o'
C:/PROGRA1/R/R-401.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:222: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.c.o'
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o kfunc.o kfunc.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o knetfile.o knetfile.c
knetfile.c: In function 'khttp_connect_file':
knetfile.c:416:61: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]
if (fp->offset != 0) l += sprintf(buf + l, "Range: bytes=%lld-\r\n", (long long)fp->offset);
^
knetfile.c:416:45: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
if (fp->offset != 0) l += sprintf(buf + l, "Range: bytes=%lld-\r\n", (long long)fp->offset);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
knetfile.c:416:61: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]
if (fp->offset != 0) l += sprintf(buf + l, "Range: bytes=%lld-\r\n", (long long)fp->offset);
^
knetfile.c:416:45: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
if (fp->offset != 0) l += sprintf(buf + l, "Range: bytes=%lld-\r\n", (long long)fp->offset);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o kstring.o kstring.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o bcf_sr_sort.o 

bcf_sr_sort.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o bgzf.o bgzf.c
In file included from htslib/hts.h:35,
from bgzf.c:38:
bgzf.c: In function 'bgzf_read':
bgzf.c:888:31: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
hts_log_error("Read block operation failed with error %d after %zd of %zu bytes", ret, bytes_read, length);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:75:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_error'
#define hts_log_error(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_ERROR, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
bgzf.c:888:31: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
hts_log_error("Read block operation failed with error %d after %zd of %zu bytes", ret, bytes_read, length);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:75:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_error'
#define hts_log_error(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_ERROR, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
bgzf.c:888:31: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hts_log_error("Read block operation failed with error %d after %zd of %zu bytes", ret, bytes_read, length);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:75:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_error'
#define hts_log_error(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_ERROR, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o errmod.o errmod.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o faidx.o faidx.c
In file included from htslib/hts.h:35,
from hts_internal.h:29,
from faidx.c:43:
faidx.c: In function 'fai_read':
faidx.c:222:27: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
hts_log_error("Could not understand FAI %s line %zd", fname, lnum);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:75:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_error'
#define hts_log_error(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_ERROR, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
faidx.c:222:27: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hts_log_error("Could not understand FAI %s line %zd", fname, lnum);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:75:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_error'
#define hts_log_error(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_ERROR, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o hfile.o hfile.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o hfile_net.o hfile_net.c
echo '#define HTS_VERSION "1.7"' > version.h
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o hts.o hts.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o hts_os.o hts_os.c
hts_os.c: In function 'hts_srand48':
hts_os.c:33:31: warning: implicit declaration of function 'srand48'; did you mean 'srand'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
void hts_srand48(long seed) { srand48(seed); }
^~~~~~~
srand
hts_os.c: In function 'hts_erand48':
hts_os.c:34:54: warning: implicit declaration of function 'erand48'; did you mean 'srand'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
double hts_erand48(unsigned short xseed[3]) { return erand48(xseed); }
^~~~~~~
srand
hts_os.c: In function 'hts_drand48':
hts_os.c:35:35: warning: implicit declaration of function 'drand48'; did you mean 'srand'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
double hts_drand48(void) { return drand48(); }
^~~~~~~
srand
hts_os.c: In function 'hts_lrand48':
hts_os.c:36:35: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lrand48'; did you mean 'srand'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
double hts_lrand48(void) { return lrand48(); }
^~~~~~~
srand
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o md5.o md5.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o multipart.o multipart.c
In file included from htslib/hts.h:35,
from hts_internal.h:29,
from multipart.c:33:
multipart.c: In function 'multipart_read':
multipart.c:81:27: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
hts_log_debug("Opening part #%zu of %zu: "%.120s%s"",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:84:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_debug'
#define hts_log_debug(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_DEBUG, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
multipart.c:81:27: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
hts_log_debug("Opening part #%zu of %zu: "%.120s%s"",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:84:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_debug'
#define hts_log_debug(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_DEBUG, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
multipart.c:81:27: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 4 has type 'size_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
hts_log_debug("Opening part #%zu of %zu: "%.120s%s"",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fp->current+1, fp->nparts, p->url,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:84:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_debug'
#define hts_log_debug(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_DEBUG, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
multipart.c:81:27: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 5 has type 'size_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
hts_log_debug("Opening part #%zu of %zu: "%.120s%s"",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fp->current+1, fp->nparts, p->url,
~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:84:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_debug'
#define hts_log_debug(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_DEBUG, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
multipart.c:81:27: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hts_log_debug("Opening part #%zu of %zu: "%.120s%s"",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:84:61: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_debug'
#define hts_log_debug(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_DEBUG, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o probaln.o probaln.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o realn.o realn.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o regidx.o regidx.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o sam.o sam.c
In file included from htslib/hts.h:35,
from htslib/sam.h:31,
from sam.c:35:
sam.c: In function 'sam_read1':
sam.c:1439:29: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]
hts_log_warning("Parse error at line %lld", (long long)fp->lineno);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:78:65: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_warning'
#define hts_log_warning(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_WARNING, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
sam.c:1439:29: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
hts_log_warning("Parse error at line %lld", (long long)fp->lineno);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
htslib/hts_log.h:78:65: note: in definition of macro 'hts_log_warning'
#define hts_log_warning(...) hts_log(HTS_LOG_WARNING, func, VA_ARGS)
^~~~~~~~~~~
sam.c: In function 'bam_hdr_write':
sam.c:233:5: warning: 'strncpy' output truncated before terminating nul copying 4 bytes from a string of the same length [-Wstringop-truncation]
strncpy(buf, "BAM\1", 4);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o synced_bcf_reader.o synced_bcf_reader.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o vcf_sweep.o vcf_sweep.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o tbx.o tbx.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o textutils.o textutils.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o thread_pool.o thread_pool.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o vcf.o vcf.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o vcfutils.o vcfutils.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o cram/cram_codecs.o cram/cram_codecs.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o cram/cram_decode.o cram/cram_decode.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o cram/cram_encode.o cram/cram_encode.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o cram/cram_external.o cram/cram_external.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o cram/cram_index.o cram/cram_index.c
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/include -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -o cram/cram_io.o cram/cram_io.c
cram/cram_io.c:61:10: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory
#include <lzma.h>
^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile.Rhtslib.win:131: cram/cram_io.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsTRXyv/R.INSTALL24fc3c222fea/Rhtslib/src-i386/htslib-1.7'
make: *** [Makevars.common:24: htslib] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rhtslib'

removing 'C:/Users/dell/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rhtslib'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘C:/Users/dell/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rhtslib_1.22.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, as long as things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to install the latest version from *Bioconductor*:

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Rhtslib")
```